# PrincipalContext & UserPrincipal how to know when password expires?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a `UserPrincipal` object with a lot of properties, but I cannot find a property for the date that the password expires.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 13):

This is the simplest approach I was able to come up with...

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using ActiveDs;

//...

PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, "username");
DirectoryEntry entry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
IADsUser native = (IADsUser)entry.NativeObject;
Console.WriteLine(user.GivenName + "'s password will expire on " + native.PasswordExpirationDate);
```

Note #1: `ActiveDs` is listed on the *COM* tab of the *Add Reference* dialog as *Active DS Type Library*

Note #2: As far as I can tell, the `PasswordExpirationDate` is in UTC time.

Comment: Great answer. thanks! a tip - sometimes, using `FindByIdentity` is very slow. mostly on local machines. in these cases, it's better to use `PrincipalSearcher`

Comment: I don't normally use the "*Principal*" classes. I prefer the DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher objects. In my tests they tend to be faster.

Comment: In which assembly does ActiveDs live?

Comment: This works, however also makes dozens of COM-related warnings show up in the build output in Visual Studio (MSB3305 warnings), which I can't disable from my side.

Comment: If **PasswordExpirationDate = 01/01/1970** ??