# Active directory - get list of users with password expiring soon

Tags: c#, active-directory, directorysearcher

I need to get a list of users from Active directory whose passwords are expiring soon (say in 5 days).

I need to do this by adding a filter to the `DirectorySearcher` as it will be fastest. I have added the `samaccountname` pattern to the filter but I can't figure out how to add `pwdLastSet` to it. Ideally the filter would reduce the user list to only those who fulfill the password expiration criteria.

```
        using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = GetXYZAccountOU())
        {
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            ds.Filter = "(&" +                                
                            "(samaccountname=XYZ*)"
             + ")";


            SearchResultCollection result = ds.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult searchResult in result)
            {
                var de = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                //long pwdLastSetVal = (long)de.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];

                //Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["displayName"].Value + ": " + DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(pwdLastSetVal));
                Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["displayName"].Value);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
```

Here XYZ is the starting letters of my users' `samaccountname`.

If I run this code I can get the `displayName` and some other attributes but not the `pwdLastSet` or the computed attribute `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` while I can see both of them in the Active directory browser.

Comment: you will be better off doing this using PrincipalContext look here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535829/principalcontext-userprincipal-how-to-know-when-password-expires

Comment: I knew we can find the Password expiration date for a single user using UserPrincipal but I need to find the list of users with password expiring in a few days. If I get the list of all users and then iterate over them to find expiration date for each of them, it would be very bad from performance point of view.

Comment: you can do that as well how are you currently doing this for a single user? well do the same thing but do it inside of a for loop or a foreach loop. you need to think out side of the box

Comment: @MethodMan that will be very expensive as this is multiple AD queries. For any half decent companies, the infra team will shut down that tool straightaway

Comment: @Danish switch to lower level `LdapQuery` classes. you can then specify which attributes to fetch in your query.

Comment: take a look at this link then @Danish, http://www.macaalay.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/

Answer (score 0):

You have to know in advance how long passwords are valid for, and query the `pwdLastSet` attribute. But of course the date is stored in a weird format.

Let's assume they're valid for 30 days. Then you can construct the query like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToFileTime();
var query = $"(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(!pwdlastset=0)(pwdlastset<={date})(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))";
```

Accounts can be set to never expire passwords, so you have to account for that in your query. The `userAccountControl` condition does that.

If you don't want to use a magic number in your code, you can look up how long passwords are valid for on the domain by looking at the `maxPwdAge` attribute at the root of the domain (which is stored in a different, weird format):

```
var domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com");
Int64 pwdAge = (Int64) domain.Properties["maxPwdAge"][0];
var maxPwdAge = pwdAge / -864000000000; //convert to days
```